# Overwriting a properties file in JUnit test does not work

Tags: java, junit, properties

in my project I load an attribute via a properties file like this (Using `org.apache.commons.configuration2`)

```
Configurations configs = new Configurations();
    try {
        config = configs.properties(new File("config.properties"));
    } catch (ConfigurationException cex) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not load properties file: {}",cex.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

config.getString("theKey",INVALID);
```

When writing the unit test for that module I would like to switch between the config values, so that both values for "theKey" are tested (true and false).

I copied the config.properties file into my test/ressources directory and it seems that this file is correctly being used but when I try to overwrite the property it never actually gets written into the file so the unit under test always loads the hardcoded value from the properties file.

I am trying to overwrite it like this (within my JUnit test):

```
Configurations configs = new Configurations();
try {
    config = configs.properties(new File("config.properties"));
} catch (ConfigurationException cex) {
    LOGGER.error("Could not load properties file: {}",cex.getLocalizedMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
config.setProperty("theKey",true);
```

How can I overwrite properties so that my module sees the updated values?

Comment: Err, sorry, but which part of the code that you are showing is supposed to write something back into the file? And when you want the test code to MODIFY the file content anyway, why don't you just put the changed content in there from the beginning?

Comment: Also note that there is no point in duplicating that code, and calling System.exit() isn't something you should be doing in your testcode?!

Comment: I thought `config.setProperty("theKey",true);` would change the content. The first code block is in my unit under test. The lower code part is in my @Test. What do you mean by putting it there from the beginning? I do not want to change the config file by hand. I want one @Test to run the unit with the property set to true and one @Test to run the unit with property set to false. I just do not have enough experience in unit testing (barely any) to make this work. The property changes the execution behaviour and I need to test both behaviours. So I need a way to feed true and false to the unit

Comment: Then the real answer is: your production code should have a way to **inject** such a configuration object. Meaning: A) write one method that pulls a Config object from the file ... and all your other code only works with that object B) now, in your test setup, you make it possible that the production code doesn't read the Config object itself, but just receives a Config object ... that your test code prepared. 
It is a REALLY bad idea to have your unit test write a file that the production code is using.